# REST url for unique resource (url with singular ?)

Tags: rest, url

I have a webserver with some configuration properties and I want to be able to change them using a REST API.

Example

```
{
    "maxUsers" : 10,
    "refreshPeriodInMin" : 5
}
```

I would like to represent this with a "configuration" object. According to REST principle I believe the best way to do it is :

```
GET/PUT/POST/DELETE /configurations/{id}
```

But in my case I have only one configuration object and I do not like the idea of have to query

```
GET /configurations
```

just for one object.

Because there is only one object the easiest solution I found is to use id=default

Would give something like

```
GET /configurations/default
```

- Is there a better way to represent a "unique" resource ? As mentionned by djmorton in the comments would `/configuration` be correct in a REST world ?

Another solution I though about would be to have one object per property. This would give

```
GET /properties/maxUsers
```

Problem with that solution is that you need to know the name of property to be able to query it. PLus you will make several queries if you have multiple changes to make.

Comment: If you only have one configuration object, why not just use /configuration rather than /configurations/{id} ? Then, just use GET to fetch it and PUT to update it... Generally you wouldn't use POST because you are not creating a new resource at a new URI.

Comment: If I DELETE /resource, then if I GET /resource what happens ? I get a 404 ? I do not know because in that case resource is then an id. It just feels to me that this is not really restful

Comment: There's no requirement that you support all HTTP verbs in REST.  Return a 405 if somebody tries to DELETE the resource, unless you want them to have the ability to clear it using DELETE.  In that case, GET could simply return a 404 after a DELETE.

Comment: Yes that is true, I just had the feeling that /resource was not really REST "approved"

Comment: If the resource is truly singular, I'd say it would make less sense to jump through hoops to try to find a way to make it work with some notion of an id in the path.  The configuration *is* the resource in question... As long as you are transferring state in a way users expect, I'd say it was perfectly REST "approved"... although it's hard to find 2 people that would entirely agree what REST "approved" meant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep the resource singular if it truly represents a singular thing.  If you will only have one, there is no reason not to simply PUT to that resource when you want to create or update it, and GET from that resource when you want to retrieve it.

If it can not be deleted, return a 405 METHOD NOT ALLOWED on DELETE requests.  If it can be deleted, a DELETE request to that resource is acceptable, after which GET requests can return a 404 NOT FOUND.

In many ways, adding an id element to the path like /configuration/default would probably confuse users because they might expect that they would be able to POST new configurations to /configuration in addition to the default one.

The key is to do something that is sensible and intuitive to consumers of the API.